# Reusing an 8 bit microprocessor? (86CH09NG)

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, microprocessor, microwave

I salvaged some parts from a microwave and I am wondering if it is possible/ feasible to reuse the 8 bit microprocessor on it? I am also not sure if I found the proper datasheet for it? ([link to datasheet](http://www.datasheet.hk/view_online.php?id=1319548&file=0164%5Ctmp86ch09ng_4125137.pdf))

[image: photo of MCU on PCB]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ROM (MaskROM)

Nope.

Well, yes, but only for what it was already used for. Mask ROM means that the programming is directly part of the silicon and cannot be changed.

Comment: I guess I could nit-pick and mention it's a single metal layer that is custom masked for the application rather than literally silicon, but +1 anyway.